# How to achieve zero cost and secure deployment option using docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, cloud

We are building a proprietary Java application based on Docker. Right now, we are using local docker installation and development is in progress. When we want to share this application, hope this should be deployed in some docker registry. Docker registry is free and opensource? or how can I securely+freely allow my customers to access my application?.Basically, we want zero cost secure deployment option using docker.

Comment: Can you expand on "securely"? Do you want the images open to the public or restricted to certain users?

Comment: @Matt, restricted to my customer

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with putting your docker images public - you can use the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com).
If you want to keep it private - you can opt for one of the free private registries, e.g. [treescale](https://treescale.com/)

See a longer list of free private registries [here](https://johanbostrom.se/blog/list-of-free-private-docker-registry-and-repository)